# Swift Quotation Mark in URL

Tags: swift, url, special-characters, encode, nsurl

I'm trying to do a request with Alamofire to this url:

```
https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];(way[highway~"^(motorway)$"][!maxspeed](around:5,45.792790,3.062686););out%20tags;
```

but it contains a double quotation mark and the cast into URL fails.

I've escaped the `"` with the backslash

```
let urlString = "https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];(way[highway~\"^(motorway)$\"][!maxspeed](around:5,45.792790,3.062686););out%20tags;"
```

but when I convert the string in a URL, it returns nil

```
let url = URL(string: urlString)
```

I've tried replacing the `"` symbols with `%22`, but it is still not working. I tried using the addingPercent but it results in a wrong url and returns error 400 or 404

```
let urlWithEconding = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
```

I also tried to use AlamoFire method for url casting and encoding, but I cannot make it work...

Comment: Never use URL with a string. Use URLComponents.

Comment: Can you show me an example using URLComponents? The part after ?data= is has to be considerated as queryItems?

Comment: If you are the developer of the API as well, you may want to pass the parameters as headers instead of URL components. I believe JSON is *usually* passed to an API through the request header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can use URLComponents

```
let queryValue = "[out:json];(way[highway~\"^(motorway)$\"][!maxspeed](around:5,45.792790,3.062686););out tags;"

var components = URLComponents()

components.scheme = "https"
components.host = "overpass-api.de"
components.path = "/api/interpreter"
components.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "data", value: queryValue)]
```

If you don't want to escape the quotes you can define the variable like this

```
let queryValue = """
[out:json];(way[highway~"^(motorway)$"][!maxspeed](around:5,45.792790,3.062686););out tags;
"""
```

Comment: I used the URLComponents and it works perfectly, thank you